# Do curl and wget open gzipped files automatically?

Tags: macos, wget, curl, gzip

I made two http calls to the same gzipped resource from two different machines - RHEL and OSX.

```
curl http://example.com/file.gz
```

The first call returned an expected binary output:

```
/�IQ���}
```

The second call returned the content:

```
Hello, world!
```

The same phenomenon happened with `wget` - binary response from the RHEL machine, plaintext from the OSX one.

Could OSX be auto-opening my resource implicitly? Can I override these settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the OSX [`curl` man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/curl.1.html), some versions have automatic decompression of lzip encoded archives:

```
-V, --version
          Displays information about curl and the libcurl version it uses.
[...]

      The  third  line  (starts  with "Features:") shows specific features 
      libcurl reports to offer. Available features include:

[...]
      libz   Automatic decompression of compressed files over HTTP is supported.
```

So, I guess that if your run `curl -V | grep libz` on your OSX machine, you will see that it has this feature while the RHEL one does not.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. Any idea how to disable?

Comment: @AdamMatan not really, don't have a mac and my wget does not do this. You could try piping it through gzip: `curl foo.gz | gzip > foo.gz`.

Comment: @AdamMatan: I cannot test either... although my `curl -V` indicates that `zlib` is active, I doesn't gunzip automatically. But _perhaps_ the `--raw` switch will help you: _When  used, it disables all internal HTTP decoding of content or transfer encodings and instead makes them passed
              on unaltered, raw. (Added in 7.16.2)_